# JQuery can I display the result then have it fade away?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way I can display the result and then have it fade away after about 10 seconds or something using JQuery?

Here is the code.

```
function stop(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://update.php",
        data: "do=getSTOP",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#rate").html(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("some error occured, please try again later");
        }
    });

    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rating li a, .srating li a').click(stop);

});
```

Comment: Why `async: false`?  And if you're performing some action (rather than retrieving information), it's best to use POST instead of GET.

Comment: @strager is there something wrong with `async: false`

Comment: @jsnag - It's best to stay away from it, it locks up the user's browser for no reason really :)

Comment: @Nick Craver if i remove it from my code will it mess up my code? I'm new to JQuery.

Comment: @jsnag, Why don't you try it and find out?  There's no reason to add jQuery options if you don't understand them.  (jQuery is, for the most part, sensible in this regard.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) for this, like this:

```
$("#rate").html(result).delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

This does a [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) for 10 seconds then performs a [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) animation, no reason to make it any more complicated I think :)